# ASP.NET MVC Razor Model state not valid on RegisterModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm having two issues with editing my applications RegisterModel.

A) The fields UserName and Email are rendered as password fields?

B) The modelstate is always invalid (and my model is empty)

I think they are both caused because I have a "HomeModel" which contains "LoginModel" and "RegisterModel" property and it passes the entire HomeModel instead of the corresponding property. How can I make it pass the correct one?

I have the following form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", "Account", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "RegisterAjaxResponse" }))
                        {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div id="RegisterAjaxResponse"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterModel.UserName)
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.RegisterModel.UserName)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegisterModel.UserName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Password)
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Password)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Password)
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterModel.ConfirmPassword)
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.RegisterModel.ConfirmPassword)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegisterModel.ConfirmPassword)
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">

                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Email)
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Email)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Email)
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <input type="submit" value='Register' />
                        </div>
                        }
```

The model:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "EmailAddress")]
    public string Email { get; set; }    
}
```

But the UserName and Email field are rendered as an password field.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kG79.png
-Can't page images yet, sorry.

And my modelstate is always invalid.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    string returnValue = "";
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    //Some code that is never executed
    }
    return Content(returnValue, "text/html");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem A: you're rendering the textfields for email and username using @Html.PasswordFor(), this will render password fields, try using @Html.TextboxFor()

And for problem B, it depends if you're targetting MVC3 or 4 and which version of .NET. 
Later versions of .NET use the compare annotation as

```
[Compare(CompareField = Password, ErrorMessage = "Passwords do not
match")]
```

Answer (score 0):

a) Because you have in razor view for them

```
  @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.RegisterModel.UserName)
```

need to be

```
@Html.TextboxFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Email)
```